# Has this light earthed itself?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, grounding

After accidentally earthing the live wire going to the outside light whilst putting a faceplate back on (patched up now), the light has stopped working. I've just been out with a multimeter to see if any power is going to the light at all and discovered something weird.

Here is the connector block for the light. (LTR) Neutral, earth and live. Simple enough.

[image: Here is the connector block for the light. (LTR) Neutral, earth and live. Simple enough.]

Here is what I saw after testing between live and neutral:
[image: Here is what I saw after testing between live and neutral]

And here is what I saw when testing earth and neutral:
[image: And here is what I saw when testing earth and neutral]

Unless I have used the multimeter wrong (very possible) it looks like the light has earthed itself after the incident earlier in the circuit. Have I got that right?

Comment: Have you got your wires crossed at the other end?

Comment: @Majenko I don't think so. The problem I had at the other end involved what was behind the switch that operated it, which I'm assuming is live and then on to the light.

Comment: Did you blow a fuse or trip a tvss outlet on the same circuit?  Perhaps an outlet that's also outside?

Comment: @SomeHardwareGuy The circuit it's on is for all of the lower level lights. At the time of the incident the fusebox did trip but the circuit is now back on an operational around the lower level.

Comment: Does not compute. As meter is on 200 VAC range reading is 34.9 VAC. You do not say idf power feed is on or off or if 110 or 230 VAC system. | Assume: 1.  PNE were originally correctly connected. THIS IS A DANGEROUS ASSUMPTION AND MAY BE WRONG. IT CAN KILL YOU IF YOU LET IT| 2. Meter is not faulty.  | If power is on you have an O/C somewhere and are seeing noise capacitively coupled. Reason not obvious but  traceable. | POWER OFF. LOAD OFF. At feed end measure PNE resistances between and to local ground. | At loadish end or mid point short PE and measure PE res from source end etc. ...

Comment: As/if required repeat with shorts PN and NE. You can EASILY build a picture of what connects to what when and with what resistance | Then "just work it out".| For even more flexibility (should not be needed) short eg PN at source end and measure at load end or midpoint etc. ie overall you MUST be able to work out what goes where. N is light contains electronics they may be dead and may obscure result if left in cct.

Comment: This is a possible explanation of what you are seeing. If either the line or neutral is broken upstream, when measuring line to neutral gives very low voltage because of the load of the light. Measuring neutral to ground gives coupling noise because there is no load. What do you get between ground and line? If you get full voltage there, then neutral is broken.

Comment: Thanks for all your inputs. As all of the downstairs lighting circuit back boxes are now live, I've decided to be cautious about next steps get some external help with the matter. I will pick post an update when the issue is resolved.